# where does port 8080 redirect

Tags: linux, localhost

that might be a bit of a silly question
127.0.0.1 redirect to the index.html page on /var/www/
127.0.0.1/drupal redirect to /var/www/drupal
etc
but when I add port 8080
127.0.0.1:8080 where does this go ?
I get oracle 10g license agreement but there is nothing else on /var/www/
where does that port number redirect ?

Comment: This would be configured in your server, so you'd have to tell us what server you're running, and what OS.

Comment: Server configuration != programming

Comment: I have apache and ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually with Oracle 10g on Ubuntu, you are setting up an Apache web server to display and run the web pages.  This would also be what services the Drupal installation it sounds like you have on this box.  If Apache is indeed the web server, you need to open up the Apache configuration to figure out what it is hosting on port 8080.  This will tell you what virtual directory it is using and where that virtual directory is physically located.

Here is a good link to help you understand where to find the Apache configuration and understand what is in the config file:

http://www.unix-girl.com/geeknotes/apache_virtual_host_conf.html

You would be looking for the virtual host on port 8080.  Under that will be the physical file path.

Answer (score 3):

It goes to whatever program happens to be listening on that port.

Answer (score 0):

Check 'netstat -lnp' to see what processes are listening.

Comment: the process in 
/var/tmp/.oracle/s#16975.1
is the one listening upon port 8080
but I want to know where does 
127.0.0.1:8080/apex go on my machine ?

Answer (score 0):

The port 8080 has nothing special. It is pretty much like the port 16738:
If no html server is listening on it, it doesn't redirect anywhere.